# Dense and weakly dense, sequentially speaking.

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, weak-convergence

Let $X$ be a normed space and $X'$ its dual. The weak topology $\sigma_w$ is defined to be the smallest topology such that all functionals in $X'$ are continuous. Then we may speak of weak convergence: $x_i \to^w x$ if $\forall l \in X': l(x_i) \to l(x)$.

Is the following correct?

We say that a set $S \subset X$ is dense if $\overline{S} = X$. In other words, given any $x \in X$, we can find a sequence $s_1, s_2, ...$ such that $s_i \to x$. Then we can say the same thing about weakly dense? $S$ is weakly dense in $X$ if for any $x \in X$, there is a sequence $s_1, s_2, ..$ such that $s_i \to^w x.$

Comment: @DavidMitra I agree with your comment, except for the first word. Don't we have that the sequential closure in a Hausdorff space is contained in the closure? Thus, if the sequential closure is already everything, so would the actual closure. Maybe I am missing something.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven I erroneously saw an "only if" in the OP...

Comment: @DavidMitra Makes perfect sense. Also I think it is a good thing to stress that sequences are in general enough.

Comment: There are weakly dense sets that are not weakly sequentially dense, though. [As contained here](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwjl-ZGRyaf1AhVNVTABHRcSD3gQFnoECAMQAQ&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.math.kent.edu%2F~aron%2Fweak-dense-sequences--final-2-6-08.pdf&usg=AOvVaw1hYd5zKR8zBcFqxJ8ok8wf), I believe.

Comment: @DavidMitra Of course I meant not enough in my previous comment. Indeed I don't think the reverse direction of what the OP is asking holds true.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven so what I wrote is true?

Comment: @JustANoob It is true that dense (in the strong topology) implies weakly dense. It is also true that if the closure (with respect to the weak topology) of $S$ is equal to $X$, then $S$ is what you call weakly dense. Which of the two statements would be your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a normed space, which is metric hence a sequential space, we indeed have that $S$ is dense iff for all $x \in X$ some sequence from $S$ converges to $x$. The set of convergent sequences from $S$ is called the *sequential closure* of $S$, $[S]_{\text{seq}}$. And for the strong (norm) topology we have $\overline{S}=[S]_{\text{seq}}$, while this need **not** hold for the weak topology or the weak-* topology. See [this paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/2101741_Weak_sequential_closures_in_Banach_space_theory_and_their_applications_in_General_Topology_in_Banach_Spaces) for an historical overview.